# (Tensorflow) custom loss function when only sums of y_true are available

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function

I'm a chemical engineer and my knowledge of computer science is not that deep. But anyway, I want to make a neural network for a nonlinear function f(x). But the thing is, I can only access to arbitrary linear sums of the function output, which is

y=c<sub>1</sub>f(x<sub>1</sub>)+c<sub>2</sub>f(x<sub>2</sub>)+c<sub>3</sub>f(x<sub>3</sub>)+c<sub>4</sub>f(x<sub>4</sub>)+...+c<sub>n</sub>f(x<sub>n</sub>)

where c and x are given and n is not fixed (around 20). For example, all I could get is like

3f(3)+5f(4)

f(1.4)+f(7.7)

f(0)+50f(4)+40f(5)+0.6f(5.1) and stuff.

So what I decided to do with the given dataset with k batches was to set x, c, n, and y_true as:

y_true=[y<sub>1</sub>, 0, 0, ..., 0, y<sub>2</sub>, 0, 0, ..., 0, ..., y<sub>k</sub>, 0, 0, ..., 0]

x=[x<sub>11</sub>, x<sub>12</sub>, x<sub>13</sub>, ..., x<sub>1n<sub>1</sub></sub>, x<sub>21</sub>, x<sub>22</sub>, x<sub>23</sub>, ..., x<sub>2n<sub>2</sub></sub>, ..., x<sub>k1</sub>, x<sub>k2</sub>, x<sub>k3</sub>, ..., x<sub>kn<sub>k</sub></sub>]

y_pred=[f(x<sub>11</sub>), f(x<sub>12</sub>), f(x<sub>13</sub>), ..., f(x<sub>1n<sub>1</sub></sub>), f(x<sub>21</sub>), f(x<sub>22</sub>), f(x<sub>23</sub>), ..., f(x<sub>2n<sub>2</sub></sub>), ..., f(x<sub>k1</sub>), f(x<sub>k2</sub>), f(x<sub>k3</sub>), ..., f(x<sub>kn<sub>k</sub></sub>)]

c=[c<sub>11</sub>, c<sub>12</sub>, c<sub>13</sub>, ..., c<sub>1n<sub>1</sub></sub>, c<sub>21</sub>, c<sub>22</sub>, c<sub>23</sub>, ..., c<sub>2n<sub>2</sub></sub>, ..., c<sub>k1</sub>, c<sub>k2</sub>, c<sub>k3</sub>, ..., c<sub>kn<sub>k</sub></sub>]

n=[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 2, 2, 2, ..., 2, ..., k, k, k, ..., k]

where n<sub>1</sub>, n<sub>2</sub>, n<sub>3</sub>, ..., n<sub>k</sub> can be all different.

Then, I thought that the loss function can be defined as:

sum(mse(y_true<sub>i</sub> - y_pred<sub>i</sub> · c<sub>i</sub>))) with respect to i=1, 2, ..., k where a·b is the dot product of a and b.

So I defined the custom loss function and main codes like this and ran them with a single FNN network with 3 Dense layers:

```
def loss_Tm(data, y_pred):
    y_true=data[:, 0]
    _count=data[:, 1]
    _n=tf.cast(data[:, 2], tf.int32)
    N=tf.reduce_max(_n)
    T_diff=np.array([])

    i=0
    while i<N:
        A=tf.where(i==_n, y_true-y_pred*_count, 0)
        T_diff=np.append(T_diff, tf.reduce_sum(A))
        i+=1
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(T_diff))

model.compile(loss=loss_Tm)
model.fit(x, np.concatenate((y_true, count, n), 1))
```

But I got this error message upon runing:

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic tf.Tensor (loss_Tm/while/Placeholder:0) to a numpy array.
This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported.
```

so I tried to use tensor like this:

```
def loss_Tm(data, y_pred):
    y_true=data[:, 0]
    _count=data[:, 1]
    _n=tf.cast(data[:, 2], tf.int32)
    N=tf.reduce_max(_n)
    T_diff=tf.zeros(0)

    i=0
    while i<N:
        A=tf.where(i==_n, y_true-y_pred*_count, 0)
        T_diff=tf.concat([T_diff, [tf.reduce_sum(A)]], 0)
        i+=1
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(T_diff))

model.compile(loss=loss_Tm)
model.fit(input, np.concatenate((y_true, count, n), 1))
```

but it raised this valueerror:

```
ValueError: 'T_diff' has shape (0,) before the loop, but shape (1,) after one iteration.
Use tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options to set shape invariants.
```

Since I couldn't make T_diff shape-invariant, I chose to initiate with a tensor with a huge size, which is:

```
def loss_Tm(data, y_pred):
    y_true=data[:, 0]
    _count=data[:, 1]
    _n=tf.cast(data[:, 2], tf.int32)
    N=tf.reduce_max(_n)
    T_diff=tf.zeros(500,)

    i=0
    while i<N:
        A=tf.where(i==_n, y_true-y_pred*_count, 0)
        T_diff[i]=tf.reduce_sum(A)
        i+=1
    #B=tf.stack(T_diff)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(T_diff))

model.compile(loss=loss_Tm)
model.fit(input, np.concatenate((y_true, count, n), 1))
```

but it raised this sh*t

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
```

I also tried to use a list object like this:

```
def loss_Tm(data, y_pred):
    y_true=data[:, 0]
    _count=data[:, 1]
    _n=tf.cast(data[:, 2], tf.int32)
    N=tf.reduce_max(_n)
    T_diff=[]

    i=0
    while i<N:
        A=tf.where(i==_n, y_true-y_pred*_count, 0)
        T_diff.append(tf.reduce_sum(A))
        i+=1
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.stack(T_diff)))

model.compile(loss=loss_Tm)
model.fit(input, np.concatenate((y_true, count, n), 1))
```

but I got this error message as well:

```
The tensor <tf.Tensor 'loss_Tm/while/Sum:0' shape=() dtype=float32> cannot be accessed from
FuncGraph(name=train_function, id=2270323096688), because it was defined in
FuncGraph(name=loss_Tm_while_body_305, id=2270325652016), which is out of scope.
```

Can anyone help me figure out how I can modify the code or algorithm and let me out of this hellbound? This tensorflow is much more complex than I thought it would be :(

ps. I also tried these two, but I don't think it would work.

```
def loss_Tm(y_true, y_pred):
    result=tf.cast(0, tf.float32)
    index=0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        calc=tf.tensordot(count[index:index+len(data[i]), 0], y_pred[index:index+len(data[i]), 0], 1)
        obs=tf.reduce_sum(y_true[index:index+len(data[i]), 0])
        result+=tf.square(calc-obs)
        index+=len(data[i])
    return result
```

here, `data` is a list of dictionaries that contains the coefficient of each variables involved. But the custom loss function doesn't seem to allow to use a fixed-sized tensor (i.e. data).

```
def loss_Tm(y_true, y_pred):
    result=tf.cast(0, tf.float32)
    error=tf.cast(y_true[0, 0]-y_pred[0, 0]*count[0, 0], tf.float32)
    i=tf.cast(1, tf.int32)
    c=lambda _, __, i: tf.less(i, tf.cast(len(y_true), tf.int32))
    b=lambda error, result, i: tf.cond(y_true[i, 0]==0, 
                                            lambda: (error-y_pred[i, 0]*count[i, 0], result, i+1), 
                                            lambda: (y_true[i, 0]-y_pred[i, 0]*count[i, 0], result+error**2, i+1))
    error, result, i=tf.while_loop(c, b, [error, result, i])
    result+=error**2
    return result
```

This one does not make an error, but the actual calculated loss is 100-times different from the loss values displayed when I set `verbose=1`, and it raises a warning like below:

```
Type inference failed. This indicates an invalid graph that escaped type checking.
Error message: INVALID_ARGUMENT: expected compatible input types, but input 1:
type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
args {
  type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
  args {
    type_id: TFT_TENSOR
    args {
      type_id: TFT_FLOAT
    }
  }
}
 is neither a subtype nor a supertype of the combined inputs preceding it:
type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
args {
  type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
  args {
    type_id: TFT_TENSOR
    args {
      type_id: TFT_INT32
    }
  }
}

        for Tuple type infernce function 0
        while inferring type of node 'loss_Tm/while/body/_1/loss_Tm/while/cond/output/_340'
```

**Edit**

I tried this and it seems not to have any errors. But the returned value here is still different from the real loss so I'm still trying to figure it out :/

```
def loss_Tm(data, y_pred):
    y_true=data[:, 0]
    _count=data[:, 1]
    _n=tf.cast(data[:, 2], tf.int32)
    N=tf.reduce_max(_n)
    T_diff=tf.zeros(1)

    i=0
    while i<N:
        A=tf.where(i==_n, y_true-y_pred*_count, 0)
        T_diff=T_diff+tf.square(tf.reduce_sum(A))
        i+=1
    return T_diff
```

Comment: I think, I know how to solve the issue, but before I will write an answer, I will ask an additional questions:  Why does y contain so many zeros? Is it just in order to make it the same shape as n? You just depicted your data as lists, but that makes it hard to read. So I guess for a certain value y you have want to use a variable amount n of x-values? and every x-value has a corresponding c-value? It would be helpful, if you gave two or three short examples for cases with small n and c. Also you should give your network architecture.

Comment: @Blindschleiche the output is a linear sum of any function values and every x-value has a corresponding c-value. For example, all I could get is like 3f(3)+5f(4), f(1.4)+f(7.7), f(0)+50f(4)+40f(5)+0.6f(5.1) and stuff. I used a simple FNN with several Dense layers that connect the vector/scalar input and the scalar output. I also thought of using multiple FNNs or (d+1)th-order input tensors to take care of each data line at once, but in that case every input has a different shape so I just chose to put everything in a single FNN and adjust the loss function.

Comment: Just to make it clear: in your example: 3f(3)+5f(4) the values are: c11 = 3, x11 = 3, c12 = 5, x12 = 4. and for the next example: f(1.4)+f(7.7) it is c21 = 1, x21 = 1.4, c22 = 1, x22 = 7.7? Are these correct? And I still do not know why there are so many zeros in your y-values? I highly recommend posting your network with one example forward pass. Because even I work within in the field for some years, it is pretty unclear for me, what your actual inputs and outputs look like.